# Accessing invited user with formula fuctions

Tags: formula

I was wondering if there is a way to access the User information page to obtain the Country and Title from that page, for people that are invited to an Event.

So, I created an **Event** and invited a number of USER/s. My intention is to access the USER's info pages of those that are part of the **"Invite Other"** section.

Is this something possible using a formula function?

Thanks on advanced!

---

Hello guy,

I have a number formula, (**total time**) to obtain StartDate and EndDate duration in hours for every single event. Using the output of that formula I make some calculations.

First I access the event's owner user Country field. I do this to assign him a currency with something like this:

`CASE($User.Country, "AUS", "Australian dollar", "US", "United States dollar", "No country assigned to user")`

We have an hourly rate for some users and those rates are assign using this type of formulas, field name **Hourly Rate** :

IF(($User.Country = "CA" ),00.00, 
IF(($User.Country = "AUS" ),00.00, null))

All this is the output of a field call **Activity Total Amount**. A simple operation "Total Time * Hourly Rate"

So the request now is to add to the **Total Amount** formula field the rates for all users that are invited to an event.

So if an event takes one hour I need that the **Activity Total Amount** reflects amounts from the user that are invited together with the acctivity.owner.

Does this explains better what I'm looking for?

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of where you want the fields to appear? That would help in getting your requirement clear.

Comment: Note that $User is always the current, running user. The schema behind what you are doing is Event -> EventRelation <- (User, Contact, or Lead) [polymorphic]

Comment: Is this by any chance an email template? Or are you asking about Event's page layout? A report?

Comment: Is on the Event page layout eyescream.

crop, are you saying that i is possible to reach the other users that are invited to an event by using the EvenRelation? I thought that this was only for contacts and leads. 

My first idea was to look into the possibility of using formula functions for this but I think that I will need to write a trigger on the Event object to accomplish this. I'm still worried about the ability to access Users, not contacts or leads from the apex trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys,

I have solved now. I need to write a trigger to accomplish what I want. In case anyone needs to test this for future code here is a anonymous block of code that you can use for testing from your IDE or from a Developer Console:

```
 //The whoRelations list contains users that accepted an invitation for an event

 List<EventRelation> whoRelations = [SELECT Id, Relation.Name, Status FROM EventRelation WHERE
 EventId = 'YourEventID' AND Status = 'Accepted'];

// If there is at least one user you can see his/her 
//name and Id by using Relation.Name and Relation.Id

 System.debug(whoRelations[0].Relation.Name);
 System.debug(whoRelations[0].Relation.Id);

//I created an Id list to pass the ids in whoRelations list to the new userId list.
List<Id> userId = new List<Id>();

//We pass all ids to our userId list now

for(Integer i=0; i<whoRelations.size(); i++){

  userId.add(whoRelations[i].Relationid);

}

//Now we just use a SOQL on the User object for users on our userId list.
//From here we can now access all user's details fields. 

System.debug(userId.size());

List<User> finalUsers = [SELECT Id, Name, Title, Country FROM USER WHERE Id IN :userId];

//In my test I had 2 users in my finalUsers list, to see the results I used this.

if(!finalUsers.IsEmpty()){

System.debug(finalUsers[0].Id);
System.debug(finalUsers[0].Country);
System.debug(finalUsers[1].Id);
System.debug(finalUsers[1].Country);
}
```

By using this I can now start building a trigger that will take the rest of my logic into the Event's page layout, allowing me to use data that are part on the User object.